# Reconnect Aperture masters with different filename?

Tags: photos, aperture

I lost a lot of data and recovered the photos that I could using Stellar Phoenix. I got a lot of the photos back, however I'm struggling to reconnect them in Aperture.

If I select a single image, it reconnects fine, however if I select the 'reconnect all' option, it shows as if it is working, but only the one photo is reconnected.

Do you have any advice or know whether it is possible to relink to masters with different names? The rest of the metadata should be correct for the images.